# Facebook Messenger API can't send attachments

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send an attachment via the Facebook API using Python Requests, but I keep getting the following error:

```
"message":"(#100) The parameter recipient is required"
```

My code is:

```
import requests

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages?access_token=<API_TOKEN>"

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
}
payload = {
    'recipient': {"id": user_id},
    'message': {
        "attachment": {
            "type": "image",
            "payload": {}
        }
    },
}
files = {
    'filedata': open('C:/Users/user-pc/Downloads/duck.jpg', 'rb')
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

My code is based on the following two links:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/#file

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api/

Note: I did manage to send using CURL and through Postman.

On a secondary note, is it possible to send an attachment using just the byte string of the attachment? That is instead of needing the actual path to the file, how would I do this on a server environment?

Comment: A `multipart/form-data` request needs a _boundary_ value that separates the different parts specified in the Content-Type header as well - and I kinda doubt the syntax you are using there automatically adds this later on. Check the documentation of the request library you are using there, how to construct this kind of request properly.

Comment: _“is it possible to send an attachment using just the byte string of the attachment? That is instead of needing the actual path to the file”_ - sending local file paths to the API would be pointless to begin with, the API can not read your local file system from the outside. Specifying a file path only with cURL or similar tools, makes those read the actual file content and send the binary data anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using https://webhook.site/ I was checking what I was sending through to Facebook and I found out that it was not actually processing the Key-Value pair in my dictionary properly. So through some experimenting, I found that you need to make use of Tuples, not entirely sure why, if anyone can explain that would be much appreciated.

```
import requests

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me/messages?access_token=<API_Key>"

payload = {
    'recipient': (None, {"id": user_id}),
    'message': (None, {"attachment": {"type": "image", "payload": {}}}),
}

files = {
    'filedata': ('duck', open('C:/Users/user-pc/Downloads/duck.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpg')
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

The headers aren't really necessary as well it seems, as the Requests library seems to handle it automatically.

As @CBroe mentioned, the path doesn't really matter, as it will just read the binary data anyways.